# xlsxwriter on python, Using conditional_format function with '3_color_scale'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas DataFrame that I write to an excel sheet. Then I want to format it so that it shows a heatmap of that DataFrame.

I figured that the best way to go about this is to use the `worksheet.conditional_format()` function with `{'type': '3_color_scale'}` as my argument.

However, I noticed that this **only colors in cells that holds integers. It wont color anything that has a float in it**. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is a sample of a code.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=selected_factor, startrow=row_location, startcol=col_location)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet 1 testing']
worksheet.conditional_format('B8:E17',{'type': '3_color_scale'})
```

I am on `Python 2.7` and using `pandas version 0.15.2`.

**EDIT**

I figured out why it was giving me trouble, the numbers were being saved as strings into the spread sheet not as floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see this issue when I run the following example. It highlights integers and floats:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20.5, 30, 40, 50.7, 62, 70]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @jmcnamra I figured out why it was not working for me, the numbers were being stored as strings not floats!